# Get total number of items in uploadify queue

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, uploadify

Hi I have implemented uploadify successfully using [this link](http://www.aspsnippets.com/Articles/Implement-Uploadify-jQuery-Plugin-in-ASPNet.aspx). One more thing I needed to complete this is I want to access total number to files in queue and current file number that is being uploaded. I have no clue about it. How can I get this?

Answer (score 0):

Probably you will need to configure something like

```
        'onUploadComplete' : function(uploadingFile) {
             uploadedFiles.push(uploadingFile.name);
        },
        'onQueueComplete' : function(queueFilesData) {
             alert(queueFilesData.uploadsSuccessful + ' files uploaded.');
        }
```

And with this info you can send it to Client if you need.

hope this help

Comment: I want to get this count in code behind, in ashx file

Comment: Can you show how you have your Uploadify configured ?

Comment: I have exact copy and configuration as in link I provided.